# WP-admin redirecting me to index

Tags: wordpress

I set up a wordpress blog in mysite/blog. When i try to enter mysite/blog/wp-admin or many other files i tried redirects me to the blog index. I can not get to the login. There is no clear answer to this here. Please help!

Comment: try mysite//wp-login.php otherwise install wordpress again to solve the problem

Comment: i tried that, not working

Answer (score 2):

Most probably your error is in your `.htaccess` in the root of your wordpress.

Make sure that you include

`RewriteBase /blog`

The whole file, if you didnt add anything else, should look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]


# uploaded ﬁles
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?ﬁles/(.+) wp-includes/ms-ﬁles.php?ﬁle=$2 [L]
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

If that doesnt fix the issue, check also the following points

- check that your `wp-config.php` to make sure that your URL is properly defined:

  `define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/blog' );`
- and in your database

  - in the table `wp_sitemeta` check that the row with `meta_key=siteurl` has the proper value of the complete url including `blog`
  - and the same in the table  `wp_options` for the rows with `option_name=siteurl` and `option_name=home`

Comment: thanks for detailed answer but i followed all that, still not getting it

Answer (score 0):

You can use following type of url to login mysite/blog/wp-login.php

Comment: Then please check your sitename/site-url in mysql database manually :)